# Can we call a sorbent-filled pipette tip "microcolumn"?

Tags: terminology

I came across the use of the word "microcolumn" in a Russian text. This word was used to describe a ZipTip® C18 Pipette Tip. It took me some time and some e-mailing to the author to realize that the pipette tip was the "microcolumn".

Is it okay to use the word "microcolumn" when describing such a pipette tip in English? Would the English reader understand?

> The samples were applied to the MALDI plate using the dried-droplet method.
>   To apply the samples, we used ZipTip C18 (**microcolumns** for desalting and concentration of proteins and peptides). We washed the **microcolumn** with 80% acetonitrile, then with 0.1% TFA in water. We next performed the binding of the sample by aspirating and dispensing it through the media multiple times (10 cycles), then washed it with 0.1% TFA in water. We eluted the sample using a 20 mg/ml solution of the matrix (2,5-dihydroxybenzoic acid) in 50% acetonitrile with 2 mM sodium acetate.